# rxjs zip with spread operator fails only in karma test

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, observable, karma-jasmine

I have an Angular application with the following code:

```
zip(...this.loadingTasks).subscribe((result: boolean[]) => {
  this.shouldShowContent = result.every((isLoading: boolean) => {
    return !isLoading;
  });
});
```

where `loadingTasks` is of type `Observable<boolean>[]`. Everything works great when running the app, but when I execute my karma/jasmine tests that look like this:

```
const obs1 = of(false);
const obs2 = of(false);
component.loadingTasks = [obs1, obs2];
// ...

expect(component.shouldShowContent).toBe(true);
```

I get the following error:

```
TypeError: Object(...) is not iterable (cannot read property Symbol(Symbol.iterator))
```

What is going on here? Is karma using a different TypeScript or rxjs version than what is used when I run the app with ng serve? I should also mention that this test was running successfully before I upgraded my app from Angular 6 to Angular 8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I wasn't initializing `loadingTasks` with an empty array and my code was inside `ngOnInit`, so it was executed before my test code changed the value of the array and so the spread operator was iterating over `undefined`. I'm still at a loss as to why it worked before upgrading Angular though.